# Runlevel 3 issue

Tags: linux, runlevel

When i execute the first command (who -r), the system shows that it is at Level 1 (single-user mode). However, when I go check using the second command (@cat), the default level turns out to be 3 (multi-user mode). I want to shift my system to multi-user mode but it is not happening. Can anyone help please?

```
who -r 
Run-level S 2016-12-23 11:27:32       Last=1

cat /etc/inittab
id:3:initdefault:
```

Comment: 1) its off topic here 2) runlevels differ from distribution to distribution. On modern distributions you might don't have runlevels at all

Comment: This would be a topic for SuperUser. What did you do to actually get into runlevel 1? Usually a system boots up into level 3. Consider supplying more information like what distro and kernel version you're running. It might be helpful.